# Google App Engine Ant Macros - Local or Production?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ant

Do the Ant macros listed on the *Complete Build File* section of [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/ant#The_Complete_Build_File) pertain to your local AppEngine server, or your actual production account on GAE? That is, if I ran the `update` target, would my GAE project upload to my local GAE instance or my production servers?

When it comes to local development, and when using an external Ant build (not from inside Eclipse), do I first package my project into a WAR and then copy it to a deploy directory for my local GAE instance, or do something else? How do I deploy locally?

Either way, how/where do you specify your account credentials (or other pertinent info) so that the Ant build knows to upload/download information from the correct GAE account? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build process runs on your local machine.

There's no such thing as "upload to my local GAE instance".  When you build with ant, use the `copyjars` target to copy the jar files into the WAR folder.  Your local GAE dev server will see the files at this point.

The `update` target will upload the build results to the production servers.

Your app id is specified in appengine-web.xml

This is in the GAE Java docs

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig